# How can I use Row Num partition by different default value

Tags: sql-server

I have something like

```
ID Mobile isOptOut 
1  123     1
2  123     0
3  123     0
4  123     1
5  234     1
6  234     0
```

to have something like partition by mobile and isOptOut
if the isOptOut is equal to 1 start from 0
otherwise start from 6

```
ID Mobile isOptOut RowNum
1  123    1        0 
4  123    1        1
2  123    0        6
3  123    0        7
5  234    1        0
6  234    0        6

select *,
case when isOptOut = 0 then ROW_Number() OVER(
    PARTITION BY Mobile ,isOptOut
    order by Mobile ,isOptOut
) as [Row Number]
from r
where isOptOut = 1
```

Thanks so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've on the right path with the window `ROW_NUMBER` function. However,

- As you want to number all the rows, you'll need it for all rows (not just isOptOut = 0)
- In the window function, I've ordered it by ID so it will always return the same values (if you order by the same fields as the partition, then they could come out in any order)
- Once you have the row_numbers, add the modifier e.g., if isOptOut = 0, add 5 to the row number; or if it's 1, subtract 1

```
; WITH src AS
    (select *,
    ROW_Number() OVER(
        PARTITION BY Mobile, isOptOut
        ORDER BY ID -- Note I changed this to 'ID' for ordering
        ) as [rn]
    FROM r
    )
SELECT  ID, Mobile, isOptOut, 
        CASE isOptOut 
            WHEN 0 THEN rn + 5 
            WHEN 1 THEN rn - 1
            ELSE NULL 
            END AS RowNum
   FROM src
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID,Mobile,isOptOut, IIF(isOptOut=1,ROWNUMBER-1,ROWNUMBER+5),ROWNUMBER FROM (
SELECT *, (ROW_Number() OVER(
    PARTITION BY Mobile,isOptOut ORDER BY ID, Mobile,isOptOut )) ROWNUMBER
    FROM  @table) as T ORDER BY ID
```

I think subquery and IIF suit you to reach your target. I created a window function and in the main query the condition.

Comment: Answers should contain an explanation, in addition to the code, to allow the OP to learn.